# Difference between two files containing file names

Tags: linux

I have two files, `audit.txt` and `server.txt`, both contain filenames. I want to get only filenames that are present in `audit.txt` but not in `server.txt`

```
audit.txt looks like

filename1
filename3
filename2

server.txt looks like

filename1
filename2
```

ideally i would want the difference in a 3rd file `missing.txt` that will contain `filename3` as per the example above.

I have tried following but the `missing.txt` does not contain correct difference,

`comm -13 audit.txt server.txt > missing.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `diff` command like so

```
diff audit.txt server.txt > missing.txt
```

Comment: thank you for  your time. somehow that is not giving me right count as i have special characters in my filename e.g. `edge.23423423_line.gz`

Comment: thank you i was making a silly mistake, you pointed me in the right direction